# Why "Sim shalom" at mincha on Shabas?

Tags: shabbat, eretz-yisrael, shemoneh-esrei, mincha-afternoon-prayer, nusach-ashkenaz

Using an Israeli *sidur* (prayer book) *nusach Ashk'naz* recently, I saw that it had "*Sim shalom*" for *mincha* of *Shabas* (including *Shabas yom tov*, but not weekday *yom tov*), even though it had "*Shalom rav*" for *mincha* usually.

Why would *Shabas* differ from other days in this regard?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10426

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Sefer HaKushyos and other sources the reason is because the Torah is read by Shabbos Mincha. Although, this answer still requires further clarification. See https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1NJHmIXg4QJZEQ2Rk04MkJUN3loRHN6Z1RWX3pQQQ

Although regular Nusach Ashkenaz doesn't do this, the Vilna Gaon was of the opinion to do so which is why the custom is to do this in Israel.

Comment: An expert on nuschaos (whose name escapes me now) answered me on this question that there are various alternative versions (like sim sholom & sholom rov and retzei & vesairoaiv (the one we say before duchaning on Yom Tov)) which are basically interchangeable. Changing between them, he said, is not a major concern!