# Personal Fast and Davening

Tags: tefilla, fast-days, repentance-teshuvah, kaparah-atonement

If one is undertaking a personal fast (let's say for teshuvah/kapparah purposes), should one add "Aneinu" to his personal shemoneh esrei at minchah? If one normally says Shalom Rav at Mincha (Nusach Ashkenaz), should one say instead Sim Shalom?  Are there are any other considerations that one should do or have in mind on that day of his fast? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to saying Aneinu, The Shulchan Aruch in [565:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.565.1?lang=bi) says

> יחיד אומר עננו בשומע תפלה בין יחיד שקבל עליו תענית בין יחיד המתפלל עם הצבור בתענית צבור

In 565:3 he brings those who say one should only say it by mincha (even on a taanis tzibbur)

> יש אומרים שאין היחיד אומר עננו כי אם במנחה שמא יאחזנו בולמוס ונמצא שקרן בתפלתו

In regards to saying Sim Shalom, since it’s connected to Birchas Kohanim (see [Shalom Rav / Sim Shalom - by Mincha according to Nusach Ashkenaz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10426/shalom-rav-sim-shalom-by-mincha-according-to-nusach-ashkenaz)) it would not be said privately, as there is no Birchas kohanim.

Some things to remember about fasting privately are:

SA 565:4

> טוב לומר בתחנונים שאחר תפלת המנחה לאחר אלהי נצור וכו' רבון כל העולמים גלוי וידוע לפניך שבזמן שבית המקדש קיים אדם חוטא ומקריב קרבן ואין מקריבין ממנו אלא חלבו ודמו וכו

SA 565:6

> המתענה ומפרסם עצמו לאחרים להשתבח שהוא מתענה הוא נענש על כך

SA 571:1

> היושב בתעני' אם יכול לסבול התעני' נקרא קדוש ואם לאו כגון שאינו בריא וחזק נקרא חוטא

SA 578:1

> כשם שהצבור מתענים ומתפללים על צרתם כך כל יחיד מתענה ומתפלל על צרתו כיצד היה לו חולה או תועה במדבר או חבוש בבי' האסורי' יש לו להתענו' ולבקש רחמים בתעניתו

The [MB 578:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.578.1?lang=bi)

> שכיון שהתענית הוא מדרכי התשובה והכנעה כל יחיד ויחיד מחוייב לחפש בדרכיו בעת צרתו ולשוב אל ד' [מגיד משנה וכתב הפמ"ג דמשמע מלשון זה דיש עליו חיוב להתענות וכן מצדד הב"ח ע"ש]

Comment: 565:4 isn't limited to private fasts

Comment: Could there not be birkat kohanim at a group private fast? The rule isn't "when there is birkat kohanim" but rather "when there could be". What would we say if a fasting kohein accidentally went up?

Comment: That’s a good question. Is that allowed? 10 people coincidentally are fasting together, can they have Birchas kohanim?

Comment: Note there is a dispute if Aneinu on a private fast should be reworded into the singular (and even though classically many answered that there must be someone else fasting somewhere, that's surely no longer true on random days)

Comment: For the record, I know someone who fasts every day.